# How to insert a paragraph by replacing a string in word document

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

I am using org.apache.poi poi-OOXML 3.17 in my java project. My requirement is to replace a text from a word document with some text(like a signature).

Somehow my code is adding that paragraph in the bottom of the page along with replacing my keyword, here is my block of code

```
public XWPFDocument addUserCompany(XWPFDocument doc, String imagePath,String userCompanyAddressInfo,String userCompanyContactInfo,String keyword) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    int i=0;
    XWPFParagraph newPara = getNewPara(doc, imagePath, userCompanyAddressInfo, userCompanyContactInfo);
    for(XWPFParagraph existingPara:doc.getParagraphs()){
        for(XWPFRun existingRun:existingPara.getRuns()){
            if(existingRun!=null && existingRun.getText(0)!=null  && existingRun.getText(0).contains(keyword)){
                doc.setParagraph(newPara, i);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return doc;
}
private XWPFParagraph getNewPara(XWPFDocument doc, String imagePath, String userCompanyAddressInfo, String userCompanyContactInfo) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    XWPFParagraph newPara = doc.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun newRun = newPara.createRun();
    File imageFile1 = new File(imagePath);
    if (imageFile1.exists()) {
        int imgFormat1 = getImageFormat(imageFile1.getName());
        newRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imageFile1), imgFormat1, imageFile1.getName(), 491066, 491066);
        newRun.addBreak();
    }
    newRun.setText(userCompanyAddressInfo);
    newRun.addBreak();
    newRun.setText(userCompanyContactInfo);
    newRun.addBreak();
    return newPara;
}

word.addUserCompany(doc, userCompanyImage, userCompanyAddressInfo, userCompanyContactInfo, "${USERCONTACTINFO}");
```

here is my original document

[image]

and the screenshot of the result document is
[image]

in the result document, you can see signature added in bottom page also along with top of the page

can someone help me fix this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem is that [XWPFDocument.createParagraph](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#createParagraph--) always appends a new paragraph to this document. So after setting that paragraph as replacement of the paragraph to replace by using [XWPFDocument.setParagraph](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#setParagraph-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph-int-), we need removing the formerly created new paragraph from the document. For this [XWPFDocument.removeBodyElement-](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#removeBodyElement-int-) can be used.

Btw.: You do not need the `int i` as position marker. There is [XWPFDocument.getPosOfParagraph](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getPosOfParagraph-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph-).

Since we need removing a paragraph from the document, this cannot be done in the loop over the paragraphs. So we need determining the `paragraphToReplace` in the loop first and then replacing that paragraph with the new created paragraph and then removing the new created paragraph from the document.

So the `addUserCompany` should be like:

```
 public XWPFDocument addUserCompany(XWPFDocument doc, String imagePath,String userCompanyAddressInfo,String 
  userCompanyContactInfo,String keyword) throws Exception {
  XWPFParagraph paragraphToReplace = null;
  for(XWPFParagraph existingPara : doc.getParagraphs()) {
   if(existingPara.getText().contains(keyword)) {
    paragraphToReplace = existingPara; 
   }
  }
  if (paragraphToReplace != null) {
   XWPFParagraph newPara = getNewPara(doc, imagePath, userCompanyAddressInfo, userCompanyContactInfo);
   doc.setParagraph(newPara, doc.getPosOfParagraph(paragraphToReplace));
   doc.removeBodyElement(doc.getPosOfParagraph(newPara));
  }
  return doc;
 }
```

Note that I do not try getting the placeholder from the text runs. `Word` sometimes uses strange rules for creating text runs. Thus in our example `$` and `{` and `USERCONTACTINFO` and `}` might be each in it's own text run. Then `existingRun.getText(0).contains(keyword)` never would be true. However, since we are replacing the entire paragraph anyway, we can also check whether the paragraph contains the keyword using `existingPara.getText().contains(keyword)`. This is true even if parts of the `keyword` are in separate text runs.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordReplaceParagraphContainingKeyword {

 static XWPFDocument addUserCompany(XWPFDocument doc, String imagePath,String userCompanyAddressInfo,String 
  userCompanyContactInfo,String keyword) throws Exception {
  XWPFParagraph paragraphToReplace = null;
  for(XWPFParagraph existingPara : doc.getParagraphs()) {
   if(existingPara.getText().contains(keyword)) {
    paragraphToReplace = existingPara; 
   }
  }
  if (paragraphToReplace != null) {
   XWPFParagraph newPara = getNewPara(doc, imagePath, userCompanyAddressInfo, userCompanyContactInfo);
   doc.setParagraph(newPara, doc.getPosOfParagraph(paragraphToReplace));
   doc.removeBodyElement(doc.getPosOfParagraph(newPara));
  }
  return doc;
 }

 static XWPFParagraph getNewPara(XWPFDocument doc, String imagePath, String userCompanyAddressInfo, String 
  userCompanyContactInfo) throws Exception {
  XWPFParagraph newPara = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun newRun = newPara.createRun();
  File imageFile1 = new File(imagePath);
  if (imageFile1.exists()) {
   //int imgFormat1 = getImageFormat(imageFile1.getName());
   int imgFormat1 = Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG;
   newRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imageFile1), imgFormat1, imageFile1.getName(), 491066, 491066);
   newRun.addBreak();
  }
  newRun.setText(userCompanyAddressInfo);
  newRun.addBreak();
  newRun.setText(userCompanyContactInfo);
  newRun.addBreak();
  return newPara;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));
  String userCompanyImage = "logo.png";
  String userCompanyAddressInfo = "111 E.Jefferson Avenue Naperville, Illinois 60540";
  String userCompanyContactInfo = "Phone: 312-100-7387";

  addUserCompany(doc, userCompanyImage, userCompanyAddressInfo, userCompanyContactInfo, "${USERCONTACTINFO}");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();
 }
}
```